# Result not shown with Visual Studio Code, but correctly shown if using ipython3 (from terminal)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython, networkit

**[EDITED - thanks to the Ludovico Loreti's comment]**

**If I run the following code (.py file) from Visual Studio Code, i.e. by pressing the green triangular button "Run Python File in Terminal" at the top right corner of VSCode**

```
from networkit import *  
import networkit as nk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = generators.HyperbolicGenerator(1e3).generate()

bc = nk.centrality.Betweenness(g)
bc.run()
bc.ranking()[:10] # the 10 most central nodes
```

**the expected result (i.e. the betweenness calculation) is NOT shown in the VSCode embedded Terminal.**

**Instead, if I run the same code directly from Terminal, using ipython3, the result comes out well.**

```
Out[4]: 
[(392, 625118.6896734448),
 (875, 204886.97319625755),
 (170, 121481.35921722073),
 (621, 72627.46666666666),
 (566, 71881.75991032101),
 (37, 62046.49111887374),
 (701, 53157.760291814484),
 (988, 45316.922735729204),
 (934, 42894.204329181564),
 (657, 32147.666666666664)]
```

**Why? What should I change in Visual Studio Code in order to see my results in its embedded Terminal?**

**[P.S.1]: If I add other commands to my code, such as**

```
print(g.numberOfNodes(), g.numberOfEdges())
```

**VSCode shows correctly the results in its embedded Terminal. Therefore, it looks like that (so far) only the betweenness-related results are not shown/displayed.**

**[P.S.2]: Just for information, if it can be useful, I have installed Visual Studio Code through snap (https://snapcraft.io/install/code/centos):**

```
sudo yum install epel-release -y
sudo yum install snapd -y
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install code --classic
```

**and I run VSCode from Terminal by typing:**

```
snap run code
```

Comment: VSCode is an IDE, you would need it only to write Python code, to run it you can use terminal of course. IPython is an interactive shell, but you can also use the standard one or zsh

Comment: VSCode has a green triangular button "Run Python File in Terminal" (a sort of "Play" button) at the top right corner. If you press it, VSCode executes/runs your code and it shows the result in the Terminal embedded in VSCode, which is underneath the Editor window. Results related to other commands in my code are correctly shown in the VSCode's Terminal (I did not put them in this post), but not the results related to the Betweenness calculation, which is the object of my post.

Answer (score 1):

The solution/explanation is provided in the networkit forum
https://github.com/networkit/networkit/issues/788

Many thanks to avdgrinten!